# How was this Sudoku puzzle derived? Help needed to complete a possible derivation.

Tags: symmetry, sudoku

Solution and rules are found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKf9aUIxdb4).
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc}
4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 9 \\
7 & 2 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 3\\
1 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 6 \\
\hline
8 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 4 \\
2 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 \\
5 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 1 \\
\hline
3 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 8 \\
 6 & 1 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 2 \\
9 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 1 & 5\\
\end{array}

I noticed that the final solution can be derived from treating the grid as a torus with each digit propagated by generators $(1,3), (3,1).$

To make this a rigorous solution as well as an explanation of how you could come up with the puzzle, two things need to be justified:

1. If a digit $d$ is at $(x, y),$  then it is at $(x+3,y+1), (x+1, y+3)$ (taking coordinates $\mod 9$).
2. If the central square has $1$ and $2$ at the given positions, then the rest of the square fills in uniquely.

The proof of claim 2 is easy assuming claim 1. Just go through the $\le 5 \cdot 6!$ remaining ways to place $3, 4, \dots, 9$ in the central square, use claim $1$ to fill in the rest of the grid, and see that only one leads to a solution. So I am interested in a proof that the rules of Sudoku and the knight's move, king's move, and orthogonal constraint implies the 1st claim.

Comment: it is just cyclic permutations of three letters (here rows or columns) It is not hard to show that, once a row in a 3 by 3 block appears in the next block (in a row as well), in fact all three rows appear in all three blocks. The elements in the row may be permuted...

Comment: @WillJagy If this is so, why isn't a similar thing true of the columns?  The column $471$ appears in the first block of the the first column of blocks, but not in the second or third.  Since the problem is symmetric in rows and columns, it doesn't seem to me that your statement can be correct.

Comment: @saul I intended both row and column operations from one fixed block. Let me draw it and .. Home computer off web, give you a short nudge if I get it all.

Comment: @saul you have a point.